# Find out how many emails were send to a Subscriber Key from all the child BU on a daily Basis

Tags: marketing-cloud, subscriber, subscriber-key

We want to create a suppression list for marketing communication. As part of which We want to find out if any Subscriber Key has received any email from any of the Child BUs in our org.
Is it possible to get the data of all the sends from all the child BUs using All subscriber list from the parent BU? In the All subscriber list we were able to find out the Click and open Activity detail from the Marketing Cloud UI, but we weren't able to find the Send data from there.

Answer (score 0):

Tracking data is stored in Data Views, each BU has it’s own set of [Data Views](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_views.htm&type=5).

To achieve your goal, you wold have to create a Shared Data Extension and create an automation in each BU separately, to query Data Views and update that Shared Data Extension. Then, create a separate automation in Parent BU, with a query logic to pull relevang subscribers from the Shared Data Extension and update the Supression list.

Reference:

- [SQL query activity](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_using_the_query_activity.htm&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null)
- working with [Data Views](http://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/08/22/data-views-in-salesforce-marketing-cloud/)

Comment: You can also use tracking extracts instead as you can specify the BUs to pull from in it. This way you dont need to make multiple queries in multiple BUs. You can just make 1 Extract automation in the top level BU

Comment: While the child BU's have their own data views, the parent BU data views have data from all business units, with the exception of a few (Job, Subscribers)

Comment: Documentation says the following, but maybe I misunderstood: „Enterprise-level data views don't include sends, opens, clicks, unsubscribes, Forward To A Friend data, and bounces. You can find this data by querying data views in the sender's Marketing Cloud account.”

Comment: @zuzannamj you are right....I have tried filtering our the Sends, opens, clicks, unsubscribe data from Enterprise level Data Views and it returned me only the records of the Parent BU only.... not the Child BUs.

Comment: yep, you will have to set it up in each BU separately